# Improve PS Scripts (jobs, ping, etc)

Tags: powershell, ping

I've prepared a script in PS, which part looks like this:

1. "$Octets.11","$Octets.12","$Octets.13","$Octets.14",..., "$Octets.51"  - I'd like to 'cut' this part of code, is it possible to write sentence like: "$Octets.11" - "$Octets.51" ?
2. My script was written to ping some devices in LAN. When some computers are active, the script shows them together at once as ACTIVE, but when it's not, it's pinging for 3 seconds and then shows its inactive, then starts ping another (inactive) and go on. It takes a lot of time to wait dor result. Can I create a function/job to ping every device at once?

Thank you for every hint!

Comment: How can we tell if we can't see your code?

Comment: Your first question can be tackled like this: `11..51 | foreach-object {('$octets.' + $_)}`

Answer (score 1):

Using test-connection -asjob (unfortunately the headers don't match the properties):

```
# 1..60 | % tostring 1\0\.\0\.\0\.0
test-connection (1..60 | % tostring comp000) -AsJob -count 1 | 
  receive-job -wait -auto  # 5 seconds

Source        Destination     IPV4Address  IPV6Address  Bytes    Time(ms)
------        -----------     -----------  -----------  -----    --------
MYCOMP        comp001          10.0.0.1                 32       3
MYCOMP        comp002          10.0.0.2                 32
MYCOMP        comp003          10.0.0.3                 32       2
```

(null responsetime is down)

(address is the hostname)

This doesn't seem to use any extra processes.